# permission denied after installed screepsmod-mongo and run npx screeps start

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm, redis, screeps

I successfully installed screepmod-mongo. But a error occurred while executing `npx screeps start`, as following:

```
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, stat '/root/.npm/_npx/4679/lib/node_modules/screeps/node_modules/isolated-vm/.node-gyp/8.16.0'
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-54-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--release" "-j" "4"
gyp ERR! cwd /root/.npm/_npx/4679/lib/node_modules/screeps/node_modules/isolated-vm
gyp ERR! node -v v8.16.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! isolated-vm@1.7.10 install: `node-gyp rebuild --release -j 4`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the isolated-vm@1.7.10 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-07-30T01_45_59_317Z-debug.log
Install for screeps@latest failed with code 1
```

The following is a list of the versions I use.

- node 8.16.0
- npm 6.4.1
- screeps 3.4.3
- screepsmod-mongo 2.5.5
- mongodb 4.0.10
- redis 5.0.5

The following is the output when the `screepsmod-mongo` is installed.

```
Screeps mod "screepsmod-mongo" has been successfully installed
+ screepsmod-mongo@2.5.5
added 15 packages from 10 contributors, removed 541 packages, updated 1 package and audited 183 packages in 85.481s
found 3 vulnerabilities (1 low, 2 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

My `mongodb` and `redis` are installed correctly, the addresses are `mongodb://screeps-mongo` and `screeps-redis`. I made the following configuration in `.screepsrc`:

```
[mongo]
host = mongodb://screeps-mongo

[redis]
host = screeps-redis
```

The following is in the `mods.json`:

```
"mods": [
  "node_modules/screepsmod-mongo/index.js"
]
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: its not an installation issue, the user does not have enough permission. The command will work with sudo. But you should be adding the permissions to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, it seems to be caused by `npm`. Switching to `yarn` installation will not cause this problem